# Analytic function definition

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading *Ahlfors' Complex Analysis 3rd Edition* and have a question about the equality of partial derivatives.

If $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function, and the derivative at a point $z \in \mathbb{C}$ exists, then by definition we have

$$ f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h} .$$

Moreover, we can write $f(z) = u(z) + i v(z)$, where $u$ and $v$ are continuous ($u = \operatorname{Re} \circ f$ and $v = \operatorname{Im} \circ f$). Now apparently it is true that

$$ f'(z) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} .$$

The first equality is true because the limit above must be the same as approached by any sequence converging to $z$. **The second equality, however, is not apparent to me.**

Directly after this a similar derivation is given:
$$ f'(z) = \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f(z + ik) - f(z)}{ik} = -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} .$$

**This time, I don't see why the second or third equalities are true.**

EDIT: I see the equality in the first equation is true now, and the reason is highlighted in the comments.

Comment: Actually the first equality I discussed above follows from the fact that partial derivative is linear (addition and scalar multiplication can be done before or after application with no difference).

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=\frac{u(z+h)-u(z)}{h}+i\frac{v(z+h)-v(z)}{h}$$You can take $h$ real to find the limit as $\partial_x u+i\partial_x v$ by definition of partial derivative.

Similarly take $h=ix$ for $x$ real to find the other expression.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Does this also explain the second equality in the second equation? Because I don't see why just yet.

Comment: Oh that's just another definition never mind.